# Nuxt JS with WebSockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt App, with one service which needs to be delivered over WebSockets.  The Nuxt App Server provides an api service using express.

I have an /api folder in which there are various *.js files, and these are routed to successfully. ie...

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/whatever1',(req, res) => console.log('req.url',req.url))
```

works OK.

However the following, in the same file, will never be reached....

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.ws('/whatever2',(ws,req) => {
    console.log('req.url',req.url);
})
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What's happening when you attempt to connect to the WS endpoint? Any errors you can show?

Comment: `VM1295:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/api/whatever2' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`  is the form of the response on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to connect the client to an endpoint on the server where no such endpoint exists. In your client's output, you're receiving an error of:

```
VM1295:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/api/whatever2' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

because you haven't defined a route of /api/whatever2. Your code above routes to:

```
 ws://localhost:3000/whatever2
```

instead of `ws://localhost:3000/api/whatever2`

EDIT:

Here's test code that worked for me:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const expressWS = require('express-ws')(app);

expressWS.getWss().on('connection', function (ws) {
    console.log('connection open');
});

app.ws('/whatever', (ws, res) => {

    console.log('socket', ws);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on 3000...'));
```

Comment: I can try lot of different paths buy they never reach the end point. ( with / without '/api' etc)

Comment: @user3094755 added an edit of my test code that worked for me. let me know if you can replicate that and get it to work.

Comment: I copied the approach, the service started OK, but neither the 'connection open' or the 'socket' functions are called. I think the issue is to do with how Nuxt JS intercepts the request paths leading to the express endpoints.